# Bigquery is extremely slow on joining 3 tables

Tags: google-bigquery

We have 3 tables (each table contains around 300k-500k records) and we want to create a view by joining these tables:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC) AS RN, t.* from (SELECT
o.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_DN,
t.TRANSACTION_STATUS,
t.CREATED_ON ,
tx.TAX_CALCULATED,
tx.TRANSACTION_STATUS AS TAX_TXN_STATUS
FROM abc.xyz.TAX_TRANSACTIONS tx join
`abc.xyz.ORDER` o on o.ORDER_NUMBER = tx.ORDER_NUMBER join
abc.xyz.TRANSACTION t on o.ORDER_NUMBER = t.ORDER_NUMBER
WHERE
t.TRANSACTION_TYPE != 'auth' AND
((t.TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ("purchase") AND t.TRANSACTION_STATUS ="approved" AND tx.TAXATION_TYPE = "SalesInvoice") or
(t.TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ("refund") AND tx.TAXATION_TYPE = "ReturnInvoice") or
(tx.TRANSACTION_STATUS IN ("Error")))) as t
ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC
```

But the query take over 2 hours to complete. Below is the execution graph:

1. General:
   [image: General]
2. S00:
   [image: S00]
3. S01:
   [image: S01]

We want to improve the performance of the query. After spending several hours researching, we found that:

1. Partition tables are not available because Bigquery only support date/time and int range partition, while our joining are based on String columns
2. Search indexes are not available since `If you create a search index on a table that is smaller than 10GB, then the index is not populated`
3. Clustered tables seem to be a good way to go. Our first thought is that we will create clustered tables based on columns that appear in JOIN clauses. But should we also include columns that appear in WHERE clauses?
4. Am I wrong somewhere? Or is there any better solution to optimize the query?

Thanks a lot

---

UPDATE:
If we only join the first 2 tables (remove third table from the query), it only took 2-3s to complete:

```
SELECT
o.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_DN,
tx.TAX_CALCULATED,
tx.TRANSACTION_STATUS AS TAX_TXN_STATUS
FROM abc.xyz.TAX_TRANSACTIONS tx
join `abc.xyz.ORDER` o on o.ORDER_NUMBER = tx.ORDER_NUMBER
```

If we only join the last 2 tables (remove first table from the query), it only took 2-3s to complete:

```
SELECT
o.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_DN,
t.TRANSACTION_STATUS,
t.CREATED_ON ,
FROM 
`abc.xyz.ORDER` o 
join abc.xyz.TRANSACTION t on o.ORDER_NUMBER = t.ORDER_NUMBER
WHERE
t.TRANSACTION_TYPE != 'auth'
```

But if we join 3 tables (even without `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`), it will take hours to complete:

```
SELECT
o.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_DN,
t.TRANSACTION_STATUS,
t.CREATED_ON ,
tx.TAX_CALCULATED,
tx.TRANSACTION_STATUS AS TAX_TXN_STATUS
FROM abc.xyz.TAX_TRANSACTIONS tx
join `abc.xyz.ORDER` o on o.ORDER_NUMBER = tx.ORDER_NUMBER
join abc.xyz.TRANSACTION t on o.ORDER_NUMBER = t.ORDER_NUMBER

WHERE
t.TRANSACTION_TYPE != 'auth' AND
((t.TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ("purchase") AND t.TRANSACTION_STATUS ="approved" AND tx.TAXATION_TYPE = "SalesInvoice") or
(t.TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ("refund") AND tx.TAXATION_TYPE = "ReturnInvoice") or
(tx.TRANSACTION_STATUS IN ("Error")))
ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC
```

From execution graph, I can see it stuck at joining step

UPDATE 2: Please take a look at above pictures. After joining, it produces 8.9G records.

UPDATE 3: I see this error after 1 hour

[image: I see this error after 1 hour]

Comment: On what plan are you? I've seen queries much bigger completing in 2-3 seconds. Try building step by step, and see what execution time you get for 1st join, then 2nd join, without row_numbering. Write join results into a table, cluster this new table on the usage. Why do yo need the row_number?

Comment: I think your `row_number() over()` will already do the ordering for you. Try getting rid of `ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC` at the end and check the performance. With the number of records you specified, this should be a quick query.

Comment: @Pentium10 On what plan are you: Paid plan. Why do yo need the row_number: because we use this view on a looker studio table, we need unique row number to allow duplication on the table.

Comment: Hi guys @khan, I have done some testing, kindly check my update

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is in your query. I created a scenario with dummy data with only the fields you are selecting to explain my point of view (just a simple explanation).

All tables has 100 rows and `order_number` field is filled with random values between 1 and 10.

**Scripting to create and fill tables [order], [transaction] and [tax_transactions]**

```sql
CREATE TABLE [order] (
    [orderID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [order_number] INTEGER NULL,
    [user_id] INTEGER NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([orderID])
);
GO

INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (3,995),
  (6,789),
  (6,964),
  (8,756),
  (2,684),
  (1,897),
  (1,828),
  (7,860),
  (5,700),
  (9,914);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (8,854),
  (7,692),
  (5,744),
  (9,696),
  (2,893),
  (3,947),
  (10,943),
  (5,861),
  (2,868),
  (9,989);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (8,864),
  (8,878),
  (2,935),
  (2,941),
  (1,949),
  (1,984),
  (6,926),
  (4,800),
  (3,734),
  (8,978);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (2,732),
  (9,773),
  (9,676),
  (3,698),
  (7,944),
  (1,776),
  (1,877),
  (6,767),
  (1,752),
  (6,931);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (8,909),
  (7,672),
  (1,927),
  (3,947),
  (8,804),
  (6,719),
  (8,990),
  (6,725),
  (4,842),
  (9,741);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (4,710),
  (6,690),
  (7,965),
  (3,785),
  (9,867),
  (7,994),
  (4,935),
  (9,959),
  (2,701),
  (5,732);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (6,924),
  (3,933),
  (5,861),
  (3,975),
  (7,821),
  (4,984),
  (9,805),
  (9,693),
  (2,937),
  (9,696);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (5,964),
  (4,938),
  (1,833),
  (1,680),
  (7,986),
  (7,768),
  (3,788),
  (2,891),
  (2,830),
  (8,682);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (6,685),
  (4,901),
  (4,799),
  (8,790),
  (2,835),
  (6,714),
  (7,676),
  (5,876),
  (3,759),
  (3,848);
INSERT INTO [order] (order_number,user_id)
VALUES
  (3,835),
  (6,927),
  (5,902),
  (4,806),
  (1,787),
  (1,805),
  (1,743),
  (1,801),
  (5,891),
  (5,667);

CREATE TABLE [transaction] (
    [transactionID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [order_number] INTEGER NULL,
    [transaction_type] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [transaction_status] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [created_on] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([transactionID])
);
GO

INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (7,'auth','Error','2025-01-16 17:36:39'),
  (6,'purchase','null','2024-01-03 01:13:47'),
  (8,'auth','Error','2023-07-28 11:49:40'),
  (9,'other','Error','2024-01-10 17:49:22'),
  (8,'purchase','null','2024-11-04 02:33:41'),
  (7,'auth','null','2024-10-18 10:34:23'),
  (6,'other','approved','2024-10-20 12:19:42'),
  (9,'purchase','Error','2023-07-13 18:39:02'),
  (9,'purchase','Error','2024-06-24 12:09:42'),
  (9,'other','null','2023-11-16 03:43:24');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (1,'other','null','2024-02-23 22:50:33'),
  (3,'purchase','Error','2024-09-24 20:53:25'),
  (4,'purchase','null','2023-03-25 01:29:01'),
  (4,'other','null','2024-02-25 13:57:43'),
  (3,'other','Error','2024-08-18 02:20:56'),
  (2,'null','Error','2024-02-21 15:19:37'),
  (4,'other','Error','2024-02-14 10:31:01'),
  (9,'purchase','null','2024-04-13 14:52:26'),
  (10,'purchase','Error','2023-10-07 18:00:57'),
  (10,'refund','Error','2024-08-20 08:05:33');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (7,'refund','approved','2023-03-13 07:29:17'),
  (2,'purchase','null','2024-03-29 18:37:15'),
  (6,'refund','Error','2024-02-25 20:52:25'),
  (8,'refund','Error','2024-07-28 02:05:34'),
  (2,'auth','Error','2024-01-19 13:10:58'),
  (10,'auth','Error','2023-06-24 10:21:12'),
  (8,'purchase','Error','2024-06-25 21:39:47'),
  (8,'auth','null','2024-02-17 05:46:19'),
  (3,'purchase','null','2023-08-01 10:23:36'),
  (8,'purchase','approved','2024-06-05 10:49:20');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (7,'other','Error','2023-05-30 05:16:54'),
  (3,'null','null','2023-09-09 17:55:54'),
  (10,'null','Error','2024-02-28 23:06:36'),
  (8,'purchase','Error','2024-08-03 13:01:26'),
  (8,'purchase','Error','2024-06-22 18:26:34'),
  (7,'purchase','approved','2023-05-04 17:38:37'),
  (9,'purchase','Error','2023-03-02 06:53:35'),
  (3,'auth','Error','2024-09-24 19:08:29'),
  (6,'refund','Error','2024-05-24 17:24:20'),
  (9,'refund','Error','2023-12-16 13:30:59');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (9,'purchase','Error','2024-05-30 04:07:44'),
  (9,'purchase','null','2024-02-11 07:19:17'),
  (6,'refund','approved','2023-05-06 21:41:09'),
  (3,'other','approved','2024-07-29 11:30:42'),
  (1,'other','Error','2024-05-13 07:47:56'),
  (2,'other','Error','2023-08-03 04:35:46'),
  (6,'other','approved','2024-01-19 03:05:12'),
  (10,'refund','Error','2023-12-11 03:57:15'),
  (1,'other','Error','2023-04-15 09:28:51'),
  (3,'refund','null','2023-04-30 19:42:25');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (5,'other','approved','2024-03-19 12:06:34'),
  (6,'other','Error','2024-04-06 06:18:15'),
  (6,'refund','approved','2024-11-15 02:26:58'),
  (6,'other','Error','2023-10-05 02:27:24'),
  (8,'null','null','2024-04-01 16:09:14'),
  (5,'other','Error','2024-06-11 05:08:41'),
  (3,'other','approved','2023-03-04 12:11:15'),
  (3,'refund','Error','2023-11-28 11:39:42'),
  (3,'purchase','Error','2023-05-21 18:07:25'),
  (2,'other','approved','2024-09-25 18:06:17');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (10,'auth','approved','2024-07-19 03:12:07'),
  (4,'other','null','2023-06-15 11:22:50'),
  (2,'other','approved','2024-03-27 11:31:51'),
  (9,'auth','Error','2023-07-25 19:05:47'),
  (10,'other','null','2023-08-10 00:50:20'),
  (7,'refund','Error','2023-08-17 19:04:40'),
  (7,'purchase','null','2024-02-04 01:05:01'),
  (4,'other','Error','2024-09-14 22:37:55'),
  (8,'other','Error','2023-05-04 02:33:57'),
  (8,'refund','approved','2023-10-24 20:56:07');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (3,'other','approved','2023-07-18 01:31:54'),
  (4,'other','null','2023-03-20 08:24:06'),
  (2,'null','null','2023-06-26 19:53:33'),
  (9,'auth','null','2023-08-19 14:05:18'),
  (6,'purchase','Error','2024-02-06 05:10:49'),
  (6,'purchase','null','2025-01-13 08:35:23'),
  (6,'refund','Error','2023-12-04 13:07:48'),
  (10,'refund','Error','2024-11-08 07:59:38'),
  (1,'purchase','Error','2023-07-26 22:24:51'),
  (10,'null','Error','2023-10-05 10:34:43');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (7,'other','null','2024-01-10 12:47:41'),
  (7,'refund','approved','2023-04-17 22:51:58'),
  (2,'purchase','Error','2024-03-21 04:33:14'),
  (6,'refund','Error','2023-12-27 07:56:43'),
  (8,'purchase','approved','2024-09-18 05:43:04'),
  (4,'purchase','null','2023-08-27 12:08:18'),
  (3,'refund','null','2024-10-09 15:27:05'),
  (5,'other','Error','2024-09-15 01:06:50'),
  (2,'purchase','approved','2024-11-20 03:38:16'),
  (6,'other','null','2024-01-03 00:40:01');
INSERT INTO [transaction] (order_number,transaction_type,transaction_status,created_on)
VALUES
  (5,'auth','Error','2023-04-16 16:44:47'),
  (8,'refund','null','2024-10-19 09:02:59'),
  (4,'purchase','Error','2024-09-18 03:06:04'),
  (4,'purchase','Error','2024-03-17 20:46:13'),
  (2,'refund','null','2024-08-14 13:55:14'),
  (7,'refund','Error','2023-03-19 03:49:58'),
  (7,'purchase','approved','2023-10-24 05:37:52'),
  (6,'purchase','Error','2024-04-14 17:50:06'),
  (6,'auth','null','2023-07-16 02:26:03'),
  (7,'null','Error','2024-05-09 04:17:23');

CREATE TABLE [tax_transactions] (
    [tax_transactionsID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [order_number] INTEGER NULL,
    [tax_calculated] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [transaction_status] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [taxation_type] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([tax_transactionsID])
);
GO

INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (2,'1','approved','SalesInvoice'),
  (8,'0','Error','null'),
  (10,'1','Error','SalesInvoice'),
  (9,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (5,'0','null','null'),
  (2,'1','Error','null'),
  (7,'1','Error','null'),
  (4,'0','null','null'),
  (1,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (9,'1','Error','null');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (4,'1','Error','SalesInvoice'),
  (4,'0','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (4,'0','Error','null'),
  (5,'0','null','null'),
  (2,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'0','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (2,'0','null','null'),
  (7,'1','Error','null'),
  (6,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (7,'1','Error','null');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (5,'1','Error','null'),
  (9,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (3,'0','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (2,'0','Error','null'),
  (8,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (10,'1','approved','SalesInvoice'),
  (5,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (6,'0','approved','SalesInvoice'),
  (5,'1','null','null'),
  (3,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (2,'1','Error','SalesInvoice'),
  (5,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (1,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (2,'1','approved','null'),
  (2,'0','Error','SalesInvoice'),
  (2,'0','null','SalesInvoice'),
  (8,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'1','null','SalesInvoice'),
  (9,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'1','approved','null');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (9,'0','approved','null'),
  (7,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (3,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (9,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (5,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (4,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'1','Error','SalesInvoice'),
  (9,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (1,'0','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (7,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (9,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (3,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'1','approved','SalesInvoice'),
  (7,'1','approved','null'),
  (9,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (6,'1','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (4,'1','Error','SalesInvoice'),
  (4,'0','Error','null'),
  (5,'1','Error','SalesInvoice'),
  (9,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (7,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (5,'0','null','SalesInvoice'),
  (10,'1','null','null'),
  (10,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (2,'0','Error','null'),
  (3,'0','approved','SalesInvoice'),
  (9,'1','null','null'),
  (3,'0','Error','null'),
  (4,'0','Error','null'),
  (2,'0','Error','SalesInvoice');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (3,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (7,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (7,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'1','Error','null'),
  (7,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (10,'0','Error','null'),
  (4,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (9,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (9,'0','Error','SalesInvoice');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (2,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (1,'0','Error','null'),
  (1,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (3,'0','approved','null'),
  (6,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (2,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (7,'1','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (5,'1','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (6,'0','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (9,'0','approved','ReturnInvoice');
INSERT INTO [tax_transactions] (order_number,tax_calculated,transaction_status,taxation_type)
VALUES
  (8,'0','null','SalesInvoice'),
  (10,'1','approved','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'0','Error','null'),
  (8,'0','null','ReturnInvoice'),
  (3,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (5,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (3,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (6,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (8,'0','Error','ReturnInvoice'),
  (6,'1','null','ReturnInvoice');
```

**1. Total rows**

If you just join these tables you should get a large number of rows compared to your dataset. But, if you filter the `order_number = 8` you will reduce your numbers of rows considerably.

```sql
select count(*) from [order]            -- 100 rows
select count(*) from [transaction]      -- 100 rows
select count(*) from [tax_transactions] -- 100 rows

select count(*) -- 10551 rows
from [order] o
join [transaction] t on o.order_number = t.order_number
join [tax_transactions] tx on o.order_number = tx.order_number

select count(*) from [order] where order_number = 8             -- 10/100
select count(*) from [transaction] where order_number = 8       -- 13/500
select count(*) from [tax_transactions] where order_number = 8  -- 14/500
```

**2. The Joins**

This means that whatever the join you do, you will always multiply the total of result rows of each table, as you can see we have a big difference between each joins (with filter vs without filter)

```sql
/*
 * Not filtering order_number
 */
select count(*) -- 1033 rows 
from [order] o
join [transaction] t on o.order_number = t.order_number

select count(*) -- 1018 rows
from [order] o
join [tax_transactions] tx on o.order_number = tx.order_number

select count(*) -- 1029 rows
from [transaction] t
join [tax_transactions] tx on t.order_number = tx.order_number

/*
 * Filtering order_number = 8
 */
select count(*) -- 130 rows (10 from order * 13 from transaction)
from [order] o
join [transaction] t on o.order_number = t.order_number
where o.order_number = 8

select count(*) -- 140 rows (10 from order * 14 from tax_transactions)
from [order] o
join [tax_transactions] tx on o.order_number = tx.order_number
where o.order_number = 8

select count(*) -- 182 rows (13 from transaction * 14 from tax_transactions)
from [transaction] t
join [tax_transactions] tx on t.order_number = tx.order_number
where tx.order_number = 8
```

**3. Solution/Suggestiont**

Therefore, if you join all three tables, you should expect a huge number of rows in your result set. In this scenario we have 100 rows per table, in your case there are 300k to 500k rows for each one.

I tried this same scenario with 500 rows in each table and joining three tables went up to 9s.

I suggest, you create a `store_procedure` with `order_number` parameter, so you can filter only what you need.

```sql
create procedure sp_GetDataFromOrderNumber @orderNumber int
as
    select count(*)
    from [order]             o
    join [transaction]       t on o.order_number = t.order_number
    join [tax_transactions] tx on o.order_number = tx.order_number
    where o.order_number = @orderNumber
go

exec sp_GetDataFromOrderNumber @orderNumber = 8
```

As for your code, if you are not going to use more than one word in your field list, you don't need to use `IN`, just use `=`. And you should consider analyzing your data to use another parameter as a filter.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [abc].[xyz].[sp_GetDataFromOrderNumber] @orderNumber int
AS
    SELECT
        o.USER_ID               AS ACCOUNT_DN,
        t.TRANSACTION_STATUS,
        t.CREATED_ON ,
        tx.TAX_CALCULATED,
        tx.TRANSACTION_STATUS   AS TAX_TXN_STATUS

    FROM [abc].[xyz].[TAX_TRANSACTIONS] tx
    JOIN [abc].[xyz].[ORDER]            o ON o.ORDER_NUMBER = tx.ORDER_NUMBER
    JOIN [abc].[xyz].[TRANSACTION]      t ON o.ORDER_NUMBER = t.ORDER_NUMBER    AND t.TRANSACTION_TYPE <> 'auth'

    WHERE o.ORDER_NUMBER = @orderNumber
      and ((t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'purchase' AND tx.TAXATION_TYPE = 'SalesInvoice' AND t.TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'approved')
       or (t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'refund'   AND tx.TAXATION_TYPE = 'ReturnInvoice')
       or tx.TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'Error')
    ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC
GO
```

You can call the procedure like this:

> EXEC sp_GetDataFromOrderNumber @orderNumber = 8

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The query produces some kind of join explosion that goes beyond the limit of the on-demand plan.

You can consider upgrading the project to flat-rate editions, as suggested by your error message.

Also you could consider spliting the analyses into smaller components, maybe rework using chunks and partitions to reduce rows.

Comment: I don't care about the error message. I just want to know how to improve the performance. Could you help me point out the way to go?